# Visual Studio 2012 Toolbars

Tags: user-interface, layout, visual-studio-2012, toolbar

Does anyone know of a way to move the toolbars alongside the menu bar in VS2012?
My setup currently looks like this:

[image: Visual Studio 2012 Menu and Toolbars]

I like to maximise code space, but find the toolbars useful - so rather than hiding them I'd prefer to lift them up alongside the menubar, and/or do away with the title bar.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option, not exactly what you are asking for but it does accomplish the goal of saving real estate.

It is a Visual Studio Extension allows you to hide the main menus when not in use:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bdbcffca-32a6-4034-8e89-c31b86ad4813

Comment: Awesome, thanks EkoostikMartin.  That's good enough for my purposes - hopefully it will hide the title bar too...

Comment: ps. I'll leave this question open for a bit longer just in case anyone has an answer to the original question (ideally without extensions), but the solution you linked to works well in VS2012 (though requires you to press alt+m to get the menu back when you need it, rather than just popping it up when the cursor hovers over it as myself and most other commenters would have liked).