# Hide main menu items in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is there any way to selectively hide menu items in Visual Studio 2012?
I found this post:
[Visual Studio 2012 Toolbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316973/visual-studio-2012-toolbars)
but this isn't it what I want.

I would like to hide some of the items like "Architecture" and "Test" etc.

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio 2012: Tools->Customize->Commands. Then select the menu item you don't want and hit Delete.

Comment: if you delete them I'm guessing you can't resurrect them if you want them later?

Comment: @DerekMitchell No you're fine :). You can hit reset all to restore to defaults or add the command to a new items manually.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may want to look at [Hide Main Menu](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bdbcffca-32a6-4034-8e89-c31b86ad4813/)

> After installing this extension, Visual Studio's main menu will
>   collapse when not in use (using the same behavior as Windows Explorer
>   and Internet Explorer).  To use the menu, simply press and release the
>   Alt key, or press and release Alt+ to directly show a menu
>   (e.g. Alt+F to show the file menu).  The menu bar will automatically
>   hide again once you're finished using it.
>
> To disable this feature after installing, use Tools\Extension Manager
>   to disable or uninstall the extension (of course, you'll have to use
>   Alt+T to show the Tools menu if the extension is enabled).

For selectively hiding the option go to Tools->Customize->Commands and then delete the option which you want.

[image]

Comment: I don't think he wants to hide the menu completely, just select itmes.

Comment: @Andy:- Yes got that. Updated my answer. Thanks for pointing that!